# Updating Bool value in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I have added a Bool value to a NSMutableArray like this:

```
[myMutableArray insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                       [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                                       …,
                                       …,
                                       nil] atIndex:i];
```

but how do I later update the value to **NO**! Seems like a ridiculously simple question, but I am getting errors such as 'Expression is not assignable'.

This, for example, doesn't work:

```
[[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] = NO;
```

Advice appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the snippet below for a test run:

```
NSNumber *newValue = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]; //toggle the value of the BOOL value

[mutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[[mutableArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] withObject:newValue];
```

Unless you're able to use literals, then use rmaddy's answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe You need to box the value into an NSNumber object for replacing.

Comment: @Eiko True.  It should be `NSNumber *test = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]`.

Comment: `test != test` is a no-op expression that always evaluates to `false` (unless `test` happens to be a floating-point NaN value, which it can't be if it's a `BOOL`).  You really wanted to write `test = !test`.

Comment: Yes of course, replaceObjectAtIndex. Thanks Brayden. The exact fix to my example, looks like this: [[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i] replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot that NSNumber piece, my bad!  Glad it helped.

Comment: Or use `@( YES )` for boxing to create `NSNumber` with `BOOL` value. It's shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Use the replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject: method.

If you are using the latest Xcode and compiler then it's even easier:

```
myMutableArray[someIndex] = @NO;
```

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, replaceObjectAtIndex was the solution. Gave Brayden the tick because he was there just before.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the time stamps, mine was first. His answer even references mine. No big deal though. BTW - A quick glance at the NSMutableArray docs would have allowed you to find this answer quickly. Don't forget the docs. They are very useful.

Comment: Ah, apologies if you did get there first rmaddy. I do check the docs sometimes. :)